# static vs reinterpret cast between pointer to POD types

Tags: c++

I ran into this problem while trying to traverse a byte array where the data length in bytes is known at run-time.
https://godbolt.org/z/-vgEk_

```
#include <cstdint>

void f()
{
    uint8_t* array = new uint8_t[4*10];

    // cannot convert 'unsigned char*' to 'unsigned int*' in initialization
    uint32_t* fourByteIterator1 = array;

    // invalid static_cast from 'unsigned char*' to 'unsigned int*'
    uint32_t* fourByteIterator2 = static_cast<uint32_t*>(array);

    // no problems
    uint32_t* fourByteIterator3 = (uint32_t*)array;

    // no problems
    void* intermediate = static_cast<void*>(array);
    uint32_t* fourByteIterator4 = static_cast<uint32_t*>(p);

    // no problems
    uint32_t* fourByteIterator5 = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(array);
}
```

Why does `static_cast` fail in the second conversion? And then, why is it valid to cast from `void*` to `uint32_t*` if that is not valid when directly casting to `uint32_t*` using `static_cast`? Is statically casting a pointer type twice via `void*` the same as a direct reinterpret cast?

Comment: @DanielLangr you can access any trivial object type via pointer of char, but not the other way around like the OP is doing.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have replied to @FrançoisAndrieux. Using `char` or `unsigned char` would still be UB, that was my point.

Comment: @bolov You're right, I had it backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint32_t* fourByteIterator1 = (whatever_cast)array;
```

Accessing `fourByteIterator1` is Undefined Behavior, no matter how you manage to get the cast working. Accessing the memory obtained from `new uint8_t[4*10];` as objects of type `uint32_t` is a violation of the strict aliasing rules.

As for why some methods of casts work and other don't ... well... that's what the standard says. And the rules are like they are to protect you from making mistakes. The fact that you cannot directly cast between them except with `reinterprect_cast` is a very good indication that you probably shouldn't.

The cast via `void*` works because any pointer type can be casted to `void *` and if you cast back to the original pointer type you are guaranteed to get the original pointer back. So that's why casting to and from `void *` is "more allowed" then other pointer types. But that's not what you are doing. You are not casting back to the original pointer type.

> Is statically casting a pointer type twice via void* the same as a
>   direct reinterpret cast?

Yes.

In conclusion: don't do that. It is Undefined Behavior.